# Use remote WCF Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I'm having trouble with a Client-Server Application I'm developing.

I've created a Windows Form Application for the Client Part and a WCF Application for the Server part.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010. The application works just fine locally but I need to separate them. I want to run the Server application in a remote PC connected to the same LAN as the Client App.

Every time I debug my Server application, it runs at **"http:/ /localhost:port"** but I need it to run at **"http:/ /192.168.1.xxx:port"**. So that I can import the services to my Client App using that address: **"http:/ /192.168.1.xxx:port/Service1.svc"**.

I have another question. How can I export my Server Application to run it wherever I want? i.e. How to run my server app without debugging it on Visual Studio 2010?.

These are my configuration files for my services:

**Client Side (app.config):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IValidacionesService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocalhostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEncuestaCRUDService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="3200" maxStringContentLength="819200" maxArrayLength="1638400"
                    maxBytesPerRead="409600" maxNameTableCharCount="1638400" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http:/ /localhost:2504/ValidacionesService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IValidacionesService"
            contract="ServiceValidacionesReference.IValidacionesService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IValidacionesService" />
        <endpoint address="http:/ /localhost:2504/EncuestaCRUDService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEncuestaCRUDService"
            contract="ServiceEncuestaReference.IEncuestaCRUDService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IEncuestaCRUDService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Server Side (web.config):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="CADBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModeloCaDB.csdl|res://*/ModeloCaDB.ssdl|res://*/ModeloCaDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=OMSUser\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=CADB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to host the WCF service as an IIS site on the other computer.

VS has a a couple of ways you can publish the files needed to the other machine, though the easiest way is probably via a network share.

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924407%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to the basics of publishing a WCF service.

Comment: WCF doesn't *have* to be hosted via IIS.

Comment: You are correct, but it appears that is what the OP would like to do.

Comment: I don't think the OP knows what he would like to do, but the use of an  HTTP based binding still doesn't really indicate that IIS is what he's after.

Comment: True on both counts, but it is probably the easiest way up the learning curve.

Comment: True, I don't know what I would like to do. I just need to run my Server app in another PC and Add my Services References using my server IP.

Comment: So? What can I do to connect my client to my remote server? Second, how to release my .exe file from my server app on VS2010?

Comment: Have you set up the service on the other computer?  If so, all you need to do is point your client app config to the new box.

Comment: The problem is that my client doesn't find my services when my server is running on the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is trying to communicate with an [EndpointAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to **localhost** which means the current computer.

It must be configured to contact the IP address of the machine that the WCF Service is being hosted on.

Here is an example of how you would do this in the client configuration file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.xxx:port/Service1.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IValidacionesService"
          contract="IValidacionesService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IValidacionesService">
      </endpoint>  
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Are you self-hosting this service right now? I see that you haven't committed to IIS yet.

Comment: Yes, I'm self-hosting the service. Why should I commit it to IIS?

Comment: No, you definitely don't need to use IIS (I prefer self-hosting, actually). I was just curious as to how your server-side was set up.

Comment: So? What can I do to connect my client to my remote server? Second, how to release my .exe file from my server app on VS2010?